# Can't extract data from $resource (consuming rest webservice)

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, typescript

I'm trying to consume a REST webservice, responding with a JSON String containing a fairly "complex" schema.

I created a model that contains every fields sent by the webservice.

Here are the relevant codes that should be a problem :

```
 public getUser(user_id: number): PlanDeCharge.Modeles.User {
        var toto;
          this.UserRest.get({ user_id: user_id }, function(){}, function(err){
            this.$window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/myapp_webapp/login.do";
        }).$promise.then(function(data){
            toto = data; 
        });

        return toto;
    }
```

-

```
 this.userConnecte = this.gestionUserService.getUser(759);
```

-

```
 export function userRest($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, $cookies: ng.cookies.ICookiesService): PlanDeCharge.Modeles.IUserResource {
        this.key = $cookies.get("encodedKey");

        var urlService: string = "http://localhost:8080/teambox_webapp/resource-rest/V1_1/users/:user_id";
        return <PlanDeCharge.Modeles.IUserResource> $resource(urlService, {user_id: "@user_id"}, {
                get:{
                    headers:{"key" : this.key}
                }
            });
    }

    app.factory("UserRest", ["$resource", "$cookies", userRest]);
```

I did a lot of modifications, trying to fix the call without success... The request actually get a response containing the JSON string, but I can't put it inside an object to be use (like user['id'] = 2)

Thanks in advance

*I deleted the last post and made this new one, the first one wasn't clear enough and people were confused*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with promises you should let Angular handle the resolvement.
Am I right, if you are actually using AngularJS 1 and not ng2 as the question is tagged? The syntax is ng1 anyways.

Some notes on the `getUser` method. Return the reference created by `$resource` instead of creating one your self. Further more, use the fat-arrow syntax on the callbacks to bind `this` to the proper context. [See this article for more on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html).

To remove even more code use TypeScripts object initialization and init the user id object with just `{ user_id }`. This creates a JavaScript object with a property `user_id` with the value of `user_id`.

```
public getUser(user_id: number): SomeModel {
  return this.UserRest
    .get({ user_id }, () => { }, () => {
      this.$window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/myapp_webapp/login.do";
    });
}
```

In your component or controller access

```
this.userConnecte = this.gestionUserService.getUser(759);
```

Lastly, the factory/service.
Use the fact that `$resource` is generic and set your variables as constants when not changed.

```
export function userRest(
  $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService,
  $cookies: ng.cookies.ICookiesService
): ng.resource.IResourceClass<PlanDeCharge.Modeles.IUserResource> {
  this.key = $cookies.get("encodedKey");

  const urlService = "http://localhost:8080/teambox_webapp/resource-rest/V1_1/users/:user_id";
  return $resource<PlanDeCharge.Modeles.IUserResource>(urlService, { user_id: "@user_id" }, {
    get: {
      headers: { "key": this.key }
    }
  });
}
```

This should fix your problems and make to code more readable. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, for Angular 1/2, I'm trying to solve a colleague problem (and she's still arguing that "IT IS ANGULAR 2 !!!"). Anyway thanks a lot for your help, we're going to try with your method and if it's work I'll give ya the answer token and a lot of love ! Thanks again